# virtualenvwrapper initialization error (

Tags: python-3.x, homebrew, virtualenvwrapper

I am trying to set up virtualenv using virtualenvwrapper for my Django project following this guide : [Django Tutorial](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Server-side/Django/development_environment#Using_a_virtual_environment).
However, after installing and writing,

```
export WORKON_HOME=$HOME/.virtualenvs
export VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON=/usr/bin/python3
export PROJECT_HOME=$HOME/Devel
source /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh
```

and trying to run source ~/.bash_profile, i kept getting no directory error. I researched about this error and thought that the error kept coming up because I installed python3 with homebrew.

Therefore, i changed VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON directory to /usr/local/Cellar/python/3.6.4_4
virtualenvwrapper.sh.

But now I am getting this error:

```
virtualenvwrapper_run_hook:12: permission denied: /usr/local/Cellar/python/3.6.4_4
virtualenvwrapper.sh: There was a problem running the initialization hooks.

If Python could not import the module virtualenvwrapper.hook_loader,
check that virtualenvwrapper has been installed for
VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON=/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.6.4_4 and that PATH is
set properly.
```

How can i reset the PATH so that I can use virtualenvwrapper?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can try it, add this to your `~/.bashrc`, it works for me

```
export WORKON_HOME=$HOME/.virtualenvs
export VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON=/usr/bin/python3
export VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_VIRTUALENV=/usr/local/bin/virtualenv
source /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh
```

Comment: For me, I didn't need to set the `VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_VIRTUALENV` variable.

Answer (score 1):

Install virtualenvwrapper using pip

```
sudo pip3 install virtualenvwrapper
```